# Extract individual values from JArray of Lists of JInts

Tags: json, scala, stripe-payments, akka-stream

I am practising Scala and Akka Streams on Stripe-payment API. I am looking to extract the transaction date: `created`  from the Json response.

This is the response (showing 2 transactions):

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "txn_1Fqdyl2eZvKYlo2CXfUAnz1z",
      "object": "balance_transaction",
      "amount": 10000,
      "available_on": 1577145600,
      "created": 1576581159,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": null,
      "exchange_rate": null,
      "fee": 320,
      "fee_details": [
        {
          "amount": 320,
          "application": null,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "Stripe processing fees",
          "type": "stripe_fee"
        }
      ],
      "net": 9680,
      "source": "ch_1Fqdyk2eZvKYlo2CwjSNI1vO",
      "status": "available",
      "type": "charge"
    },
    {
      "id": "txn_1Fqdyk2eZvKYlo2C7MuBhLpe",
      "object": "balance_transaction",
      "amount": 2000,
      "available_on": 1577145600,
      "created": 1576581158,
      "currency": "usd",
      "description": "テスト支払い",
      "exchange_rate": null,
      "fee": 88,
      "fee_details": [
        {
          "amount": 88,
          "application": null,
          "currency": "usd",
          "description": "Stripe processing fees",
          "type": "stripe_fee"
        }
      ],
      "net": 1912,
      "source": "ch_1Fqdyk2eZvKYlo2Ccg96i1QQ",
      "status": "available",
      "type": "charge"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": true,
  "url": "/v1/balance_transactions"
}
```

It can vary from 1 to 100 transactions. So far I have been able to extract the value I need when there is only 1 transaction. I need to be able to extract values when there are multiple results. At the moment the value is hardcoded as: `case Some(JArray(List(JInt(int))))`.

My code:

```
 def epochToDate(epochMillis: BigInt): String = {
    val convertedToLong = epochMillis * 1000L
    val df:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    df.format(convertedToLong)
  }

  val stripe = new Stream("txn_1Fqdyl2eZvKYlo2Cn0OSmwaY", "starting_after", hasMoreFromJson, 1, idFromJson)

  stripe.asSource().runForeach(id => {

    val rawValue = (parse(id) \ "data" \ "created").toOption
    rawValue match {

      case Some(JArray(List(JInt(int)))) => println("Date: " + epochToDate(int))
      case _ => println("Value not present in JSON")
    }
  })
```

Comment: What json library are you using? What version of akka streams?

Comment: @mfirry The library is Json4s Jackson and the Akka Streams version is 2.6.1

Comment: try `(parse(id) \ "data" \\ "created").toOption`. You should get back a list of `created` objects

Comment: @mfirry Thank you. The output for rawValue was: ```Some(JObject(List((created,JInt(1576581159)), (created,JInt(1576581158)))))``` I am still unclear how to print out the individual dates though.

Comment: off the top of my head
```
    rawValue match {
      case l: Option[JObject] =>
        l match {
          case Some(j) => j.obj.foreach(println)
          case None    => println("oh no!")
        }
```

Comment: @mfirry You are a wonderful human being! Got it working just the way it needs to (albeit a little messy) ```case l: Option[JObject] => l match { case Some(j) => j.obj.foreach(i => i._2 match { case JInt(int) => println("Date: " + epochToDate(int))})}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
val rawValue = (parse(id) \ "data" \\ "created").toOption
rawValue match {
  case createdObjOpt: Option[JObject] =>
    createdObjOpt match {
      case Some(createdObj) =>
        createdObj.obj.foreach { created =>
          println(created)
        }
      case None => println("oh no!")
    }
  case _ => println("Value not present in JSON")
}
```